# Is there a wait or sleep command in web js?

Tags: javascript

I am making something where the background is changing slowly but the colors change to fast so I was wondering if there was a sleep command of web js

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

You can use setInterval if you want to change it:

```
var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
var count = 0;


setInterval(function () {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[count];
  count ++ ;

  if(count >= colors.length){
      count = 0;
  }
},1000)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kemiller2002/od5ho3f2/

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do an animation or transition for just a background read about transitions in css and make it with css for performance and simplicity sake.

https://www.google.bg/search?q=css+transition+change+background+image&oq=css+transition+change+background+image&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.261j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

CSS animations are a good way to go.

```
@keyframes example {
    from {background-color: red;}
    to {background-color: purple;}
}


div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    /* Reference her here */
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp